# A mountain riddle

Tags: riddle, geography, anagram

In school, I'm mostly concerned with geometry. However, both in Europe and in Asia I may see my rearrangements from above.

What am I?

--- EDIT ---

The question has been edited in its tags.

Comment: This *seems* underspecified. You may need to flesh it out a bit, so the intended answer is clearly correct and alternative guesses are more clearly ruled out.

Comment: @Rubio I've added the "anagram" tag, which should now make the question clearer (and much easier)

Answer (score 1):

Some insights:

both in Europe and in Asia

> Ural mountain range

may see my rearrangements from above

> Topography may be determined from an aerial view and fits in with "concerned with geometry"

Comment: Nice attempt, but not the right answer. Yet, some word you have written might contain a hint in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess:

Both in Europe and Asia

> Caucasus Mountain Range

I'm mostly concerned with geometry

> Lots of geology and patterns - could relate to geometry

Comment: Nice attempt, too, but it doesn't quite explain the geometry part. Please, also note that I've added the "anagram" tag